# Solving Brownian Motion Probabilities

Tags: self-study, brownian-motion

I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve this probability. I'm mostly confused about handling the dX(t) equation. Am I supposed to utilize Ito's Lemma with the dX(t) equation?

[image]

Comment: Whether you use Ito's Lemma, or pray to the heavens above, one way or another you better solve (integrate) the stochastic differential equation to find the distribution of X(10).

Comment: that gave me an idea and was a very helpful start. thanks!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: (I see no reason that this needs to be closed.)

Comment: I'm curious since I've never worked with Ito's calculus. I know that the realization at time 10 is Gaussian, and I know that the covariance between realizations between in stationary Brownian motion. What's the relationship between the covariance and drift if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) for a solution to this stochastic differential
equation, for which we have the general solution

$$
ln \frac{S_t}{S_0} = (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t
$$

The key point in the reference is that

$$
\begin{align}
d(\ln S_t) &= \frac{d S_t}{S_t} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2} dS_t dS_t \\
&= \frac{d S_t}{S_t} -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{S_t^2} \sigma^2 S_t^2 dt
\end{align}
$$

Think about rearranging the first equation and about the properties of a Brownian motion,
specifically that $(Z_{t} - Z_s) \sim N(0, t - s)$

Also note that if $Y$ has a normal distribution then $X = e^Y$ has a [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Comment: You really shouldn't have completely solved the homework problem. But it was good of you to leave an error in the solution.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Sorry was unaware of the rules regarding this / whether in fact this is homework? Is there guidelines somewhere related to this?

Comment: Look here http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info . It was linked in gung's comment above.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone My mistake, I have attempted to edit appropriately

Comment: Appreciate your effort, but you seemed to have left the most "intellectual" part completely solved.  I suppose it's academic now, given access to edit history.